# How to make a underline of a <a> tag change color when hovering over it

Tags: html, css

How can I change the colour of underline of a `<a>` tag when hovering over it?

I done some research and as you cannot directly change the colour of the line you can use the - `border-bottom` option, I have tried this but when I open it in chrome nothing happens when hovering over it.

```css
.nav-main {
  width:100%;
  background-color: #222;
  height:70px;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-main > ul {
  margin:0;
  float:left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav-item {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:15px 20px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;   
}

.nav-item:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #00cc00;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main" id="navMain">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item"> HOME</a>                              
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">ABOUT US </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">PORTFOLIO </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">SERVICES </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">CONTACT US </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**JS FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/dgc4q/42/

Comment: And you thinking that border invisible and setup color cause visibility of border? You must write full border declaration: border-bottom: 2px solid  #00cc00 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `border-bottom-color` the browser assome that you defined the rest of the border's properties ([`type`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp) and [`width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp)). You didn't do it.

So, you need to change

```css
border-bottom-color: #00cc00;
```

to

```css
border-bottom: 1px solid #00cc00;
```

**Live:**

```css
.nav-main {
  width:100%;
  background-color: #222;
  height:70px;
  color:#fff;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-main > ul {
  margin:0;
  float:left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-main > ul > li {
  float:left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav-item {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:15px 20px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;   
}

.nav-item:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00cc00;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main" id="navMain">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item"> HOME</a>                              
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">ABOUT US </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">PORTFOLIO </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">SERVICES </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item">CONTACT US </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You possibly can't change the underline color of an anchor tag.

```
 .nav-item:hover{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #00cc00;
 }
```

Or

```
.nav-item:hover{
border-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #00cc00;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change .nav-item to this:

```
.nav-item {
display:inline-block;
padding:15px 20px;
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;   
border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}

.nav-item:hover {
    border-bottom:1px solid #00cc00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: red;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: hotpink;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b><a href="#" target="_blank">This is a link</a></b></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!